# Java access to intermediate CAs from Windows keystores?

Tags: java, windows, x509certificate

I need to build a certificate chain on Windows, from an X.509 smart card cert through one or more intermediate CAs to a root CA. That's easy when the CA certs are in a JKS keystore, but I need to use the Windows keystores as well.

I can get the root CA cert from "Windows-ROOT", but I can't get to the "Intermediate Certification Authorities" keystore.

Has anyone done this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

The SunMSCAPI Cryptographic provider does only support two keystores: `Windows-MY` (personal certificate store) and `Windows-ROOT` (trusted authorities certificate store), thus I don't thinks it is possible to directly  access to other windows certificate stores. However it may not be necessart since it seems that the `Windows-MY` keystore is able to build certificate chains with the certificates from other stores.

Here is a code snippet I use to test it:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
ks.load(null, null) ;
Enumeration en = ks.aliases() ;
while (en.hasMoreElements()) {
    String aliasKey = (String)en.nextElement() ;
    Certificate c = ks.getCertificate(aliasKey) ;
    System.out.println("---> alias : " + aliasKey) ;
    if (ks.isKeyEntry(aliasKey)) {
        Certificate[] chain = ks.getCertificateChain(aliasKey);
        System.out.println("---> chain length: " + chain.length);
        for (Certificate cert: chain) {
            System.out.println(cert);
    }
}
```

If I add a single certificate with private key in the personal certificate store the chain length is 1. After adding the CA in the intermediate CA certificate store the I launch the program a second time and the chain length is now 2.

**UPDATE (April, 2nd)**
It is possible to programmatically add certificates in the `Windows-MY` and `Windows-ROOT` keystore with some limitations:

- when adding a certificate in the `Windows-ROOT` the user is prompted for confirmation
- all certificate added in the `Windows-MY` keystore is a `TrustedCertificateEntry` (from the keystore point of view, not the Windows point of view). The keystore seems to build the longest possible chain with all available certificates.
- the certifcates with no associated private key are not visible in the Windows certificate store browser but it is possible to programmatically delete them.

Adding a certificate in a keystore is straightforward:

```
Certificate c = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509").generateCertificate(new FileInputStream("C:/Users/me/Downloads/myca.crt"));
KeyStore.TrustedCertificateEntry entry = new KeyStore.TrustedCertificateEntry(c);
ks.setEntry("CA1", entry , null);
```

Comment: Yes, there's no problem if the user's cert is in the personal store. I wonder if I can add it programmatically?

Comment: That works! I retrieve my user's cert from the smart card, programmatically add it to the Windows-MY store, then build the chain using the Windows keystore.

Answer (score 1):

Jcs had the answer, but I want to show some pseudocode so:

```
// load the Windows keystore
KeyStore winKeystore = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY", "SunMSCAPI");
winKeystore.load(null, null);

// add the user's smart card cert to the keystore
winKeystore.setCertificateEntry(myAlias, userCertificate);

// build the cert chain! this will include intermediate CAs
Certificate[] chain = winKeystore.getCertificateChain(myAlias);
```

Windows cert chains aren't validated as they're built, but now you can do the usual thing of creating a CertPath and PKIXParameters and using them to validate the chain.

```
CertPathValidator certPathValidator = CertPathValidator.getInstance(CertPathValidator.getDefaultType());
certPathValidator.validate(certPath, params);
```