# Java equivalent to x509certificate2ui

Tags: java, netbeans, applet, digital-signature, x509certificate

Anyone knows of any equivalent to ASP.NET X509Certificate2UI in JAVA?

Need to develop a java applet that needs to access the local windows certificates store.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can access the Windows certificate stores in Java using specific KeyStore types:

The system certificate store alias `"Windows-Root`" and user certificate store alias "`Windows-MY`":

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
Certificate c = ks.getCertificate(aliasKey);
```

For more code samples see:

- [Java access to intermediate CAs from Windows keystores?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5476974/java-access-to-intermediate-cas-from-windows-keystores)
- [Access Microsoft CryptoAPI and Its Cryptographic Services](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/security-137537.html#1)

Comment: For the GUI, I guess you could take dialogs from [Portecle](http://portecle.sourceforge.net/) together with above information. I don't think there is a specific standalone dialog anywhere in standard Java API (although it may be present for some tool or other).